# Pass number as part of variable name in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to pass a number in Shiny, and then use that as part of a variable name that determines which variable is used in the output.

In a simple example with a dataframe(df) that has two variables var1 and var2, I'd like to allow the user to select 1 or 2, and use that to refer to var1 or var2. (In my real situation these are years and the output is a map.) My guess would be something like this:

```
library(shiny)

var1=c(1,2,3,4)
var2=c(2,4,6,8)
df=data.frame(var1, var2)

ui<-fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "year",
    label = "Choose a variable",
    value = 2, min = 1, max = 3),
  plotOutput("yr")
)
server<- function(input, output) {
  output$yr <-  renderPlot({
    title <- "hist of var 1 or 2"
    hist(df$var(input$year)????, main = title)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The line with the ???? is the obvious problem.

Comment: Can you use `df[[ paste0("var", input$year) ]]`?

Comment: `hist(df[[ paste0("var", input$year]]))` doesn't seem to work, nor does it with a $before var or quotes around input$year.

Answer (score 0):

Found something that works:

```
hist(unlist(df[paste0("var", input$year)]))
```